# Can't get header to display in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyside

I have a TreeView that I'm unable to see headers for. In my class definition for the QAbstractItemModel, I'm implementing the headerData() function as follows:

```
def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return '' # empty string since QVariant isn't in PySide
    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
        return 'TEST'
    return ''
```

If I implement headerData(), the header simply disappears. Without it, I just get a generic horizontal header with numeric labels (1,2,3, etc.). Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> **PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.headerData(section, orientation[,
> role=Qt.DisplayRole])**
>
> Parameters:
> **section** – PySide.QtCore.int
>
> **orientation** – PySide.QtCore.Qt.Orientation
>
> **role** – PySide.QtCore.int
> Return type:   object

This returns an int type, but Display role is part of the **QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole** enumeration

To solve I propose the following code:

```
def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=0):
    role =  QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole(role)
    if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return None

    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
        return "Test"
    return None
```

[image]

Comment: This makes perfect sense, but unfortunately I'm still not seeing a header. I tried printing the `ItemDataRole` from within that function, and it seems the `DisplayRole` isn't even being used... it's all `SizeHintRole`. Everything else in the tree view is still displaying normally.

Comment: You could share your complete code please through drive, dropbox or similar to test it please.

Comment: I can't post my exact code, but the code I'm basing mine off is from [here](http://kylemr.blogspot.com/2013/04/pyqt-drag-and-drop-outliner-like.html). It's intended for use in Maya, but the data could be replaced with anything. All I've done is change the implementation from PyQt to PySide, by omitting QVariants and changing the code you suggested earlier.

Comment: Osea share the code of your model and the data that I can use, I do not want to share your project.

Comment: I will adapt the PyQt4 link code to PySide, what version of python and pyside are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7, Maya 2016 uses Qt 4.8.6, PySide 1.2.0 final.

Comment: @toadstorm If my answer helps, mark it as correct, please.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by returning `None` as the default return value instead of an empty string. I'm seeing the header now, as well as getting values printed for all of the other roles besides `SizeHintRole`. Thank you for your help!